# How to send Hex Values via Bluetooth in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

i want to send a hex string in android via bluetooth/SPP
i tried this:

> out = sock.getOutputStream();

```
String myHexString = Integer.toHexString(80) + " "
        + Integer.toHexString(2) + " " + Integer.toHexString(0)
        + " " + Integer.toHexString(48);
```

to send this String:

```
out.write(myHexString.getBytes());
```

but didn't work...

any help?

Comment: Your going to have to give more context than this. What is sock? Is it a Bluetooth connection? A dirty sock? How are you connecting to the Bluetooth device? ARE you connected to the Bluetooth device? Please provide more code. Also "it didn't work" does not give enough information about the issue. Post errors as well or a better description of HOW it didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

problem solved with this:

```
private boolean connected = false;
private BluetoothSocket sock;
private InputStream in;
private OutputStream out;

zee = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(
        "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX");
    m = zee.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
        new Class[] { int.class });
    sock = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(zee, Integer.valueOf(1));
    sock.connect();
    in = sock.getInputStream();
    out = sock.getOutputStream();

char[] test = { 0x55, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x50, 0x2, 0x0,
        0x30, 0xD7 };

for(int k=0; k < test.lenght; k++){
new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream()).writeByte(test[k]);
}
```

Comment: Seeing this solution: Your previous solution couldn't have worked. What you did there was to convert the values into a string and send the C-Like string. But if you want to send the actual values, this approach was simply wrong (instead of sendig the value `0x55` you would have send the sequence `{0x30, 0x78, 0x35, 0x35}` which is `"0x55"`)

Comment: Yes, i didn't send it binary. In my terminal for serial port, i saw the difference. Thank you!

Comment: It works perfectly ! May I upvote this answer one thousand times ?

Comment: Can any one explain about "zee".?

Comment: zee is a BluetoothAdapter... private BluetoothAdapter zee;