# Send hex code to bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I have hex code like 0x38 , 0x39, 0xC0 and 0xE8 , i want to send this hex code as it is to blue-tooth, no need of conversion to hex or int. i used this code for sending in my app(blue-tooth Activity):

```
     byte[] hex_txt = {(byte)0x38, (byte)0x39, (byte)0xC0, (byte)0xE8};
     OutputStream outStream;
     try {
    outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        outStream.write(hex_txt);
        System.out.println("byte sent: " + hex_txt);
         }
```

When i send this code to blue-tooth, it send further to Arduino board where it has to match these hex codes and do some operations.My arduino code is:

```
   if(Serial.available()>3)
    {

          if(Serial.read()==0x38 && Serial.read()==0x39)
          code=Serial.read()+Serial.read()*256;
          irsend.sendCode(code,16);
          Serial.println("code sent is");
          Serial.println(code,DEC);
   }
```

No Problem with this Arduino code but what 'm sending from my app to blue-tooth may be wrong..so it is not matching. In what type i need to send these hex codes?

Comment: The code looks OK to me. Which bytes do you receive instead of the expected ones?

Comment: @domsom Thank for replay. I was getting actually signed numbers like -64 ...so i changed like this  byte a = -64;int b = ((int)a) & 0xFF; So this gives me unsigned number.

Comment: And dont you want `Serial.println(code,HEX);`?

Comment: Also, if you think it's in the Android code have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037414/how-to-send-hex-values-via-bluetooth-in-android

Comment: @EricFossum i 'l change to Serial.println(code, HEX);i'l try.

Comment: @EricFossum that code,HEX works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-64` in decimal is probably a representation of `0xC0` (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations). I'm not into Arduino code, but I'd suggest you make sure the values returned by `Serial.read()` is interpreted as an unsigned integers/bytes. This will get you around manually interpreting the signed bit representation and number output.

Comment: Yes you are right. From Arduino code i was getting signed numbers. so there only i changed the declaration of code to unsigned int code.